# Troubles with errno.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, header-files

I'm coding a simple SDL program with VC10. The problem that I am having is at compiling the program:

> Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'errno.h': No such file
>   or directory c:\program files\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cerrno 14
>
> Error 2 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'errno.h': No such file
>   or directory c:\program files\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cerrno 14
>
> Error 3 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'errno.h': No such file
>   or directory c:\program files\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cerrno 14
>
> Error 4 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'errno.h': No such file
>   or directory c:\program files\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\cerrno 14

I'm not sure what could be the problem. I don't have an `errno.h` file in my includes. And I have no idea of where to get it or if it was there. What can I do? I have been looking for an `errno.h` file around but all seem aimed at Linux platforms.

Comment: Must question why on earth a C++ app is using errno.

Comment: The C++ app is not including errno.h, it is using cerrno. It is Microsoft's cerrno file that includes errno.h (as is evident from the error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bad installation, the file errno.h is missing. It should be somewhere in compiler includes and you need it because cerrno refers to it.

Comment: Running the VS2015 installer again and choosing to repair the installation worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

did you install the SP1 for VS2010, if yes, you can install Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1 to resolve the issue,
see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/31/10148110.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was re-running the installer, selecting "Individual Components", and adding the older common tools (v140).

Comment: its also happening with visual studio 2017, am trying to compile a project made for visual studio 2015

Comment: And did you install the older common tools (v140)? They don't come with 2017 by default.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing windows universal CRT SDK

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. retarget the windows SDK version in project configuration properties to a version installed on the system, this solved the issue for me.